# MySQL8.2configuration

Tags: mysql

I have a complete MySQL 8.2 configuration file that I am using, along with optimizations. Can you point out what is incorrect, what needs to be modified, and where further optimizations can be made?

```
[client]
port    = 3306
#socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
socket  = /data/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysql]
prompt = "\u@mysqldb \R:\m:\s [\d]> "
no_auto_rehash
pager = "less -i -n -S"
[mysqld]
user    = mysql
port    = 3306
server_id = 3306
basedir = /usr/local/mysql
datadir = /data/mysql/data
#socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
socket  = /data/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file = /data/mysql/run/mysql.pid
general_log_file  = /data/mysql/log/mysql-access.log
character_set_server = UTF8MB4
plugin_dir = /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin 
default_time_zone = "+8:00"
admin_address = '127.0.0.1'
admin_port = 33062
sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

skip_name_resolve = 1
lower_case_table_names = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1


#performance setttings
lock_wait_timeout = 3600
open_files_limit    = 65535
back_log = 1024
max_connections = 1000
max_connect_errors = 1000000
table_open_cache = 1024
table_definition_cache = 1024
thread_stack = 512K
max_allowed_packet = 128M
#key_buffer_size=1024M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
join_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 768
interactive_timeout = 600
wait_timeout = 600
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M

#log settings
log_timestamps = SYSTEM
log-error       = /data/mysql/log/mysql-error.log
slow_query_log_file = /data/mysql/data/slow.log
log_error_verbosity = 2
slow_query_log = 1
log_slow_extra = 1
long_query_time = 2
min_examined_row_limit = 100
log_slow_admin_statements = 1
log_slow_replica_statements = 1
log-bin         = /data/mysql/binlog/binlog
log-bin-index   = binlog.index
sync_binlog = 1
binlog_cache_size = 4M
max_binlog_size = 1G
binlog_rows_query_log_events = 1

binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 259200
binlog_checksum = CRC32

#myisam settings
key_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M

#replication settings
relay_log_recovery = 1
relay-log-purge = 1
relay-log       = /data/mysql/relay-log/slave_relay_bin
relay-log-index = slave_relay_bin.index
replica_parallel_workers = 8
transaction_write_set_extraction=XXHASH64
binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking = WRITESET
replica_preserve_commit_order = 1
replica_checkpoint_period = 2
skip_replica_start
log_replica_updates
gtid_mode = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency = TRUE

replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config=ON
replication_sender_observe_commit_only=ON


transaction_isolation = REPEATABLE-READ
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_data_home_dir    = /data/mysql/innodb
innodb_log_group_home_dir       = /data/mysql/innodb
innodb_undo_directory = /data/mysql/data/undolog
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_redo_log_capacity = 2G
innodb_max_undo_log_size = 4G
innodb_ddl_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_io_capacity = 4000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 8000
innodb_open_files = 65535
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_lru_scan_depth = 4000
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 10
innodb_rollback_on_timeout = 1
innodb_print_all_deadlocks = 1
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size = 4G
innodb_print_ddl_logs = 1
innodb_status_file = 1
innodb_status_output = 0
innodb_status_output_locks = 1
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 67108864
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = OFF
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages = 500

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 128M

[mysqld_safe]      
nice=-20                                                                         
open-files-limit=65535                                                               
malloc-lib=/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1
```

Comment: Optimizations are based on operational use. They aren't just to be edited because they exist.

Comment: I could ask you why do you have those config options set to the values they are set to? I mean, why did you choose those values? You might answer that you don't know, because you don't understand your application's workload enough to know why those values were chosen (perhaps they were chosen by someone else). If that's the case, then why do you expect us to have greater knowledge of your application's needs than you do?

Comment: One config option stands out to me: I would make sure `sql_mode` includes `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. That's not an optimization, it's just to ensure correct SQL semantics.

Comment: The installation should have provided "reasonable" default values for anything that it set.  Don't bother making any changes until you find a need or you know that you are doing something unusual.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.